# Error in creating txt file Android

Tags: java, android, file

I'm trying to create a file to save a flag which I'll need in further executions. 
This is the code which I wrote in order to create the file:

```
FileOutputStream fileout=openFileOutput("flag.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
OutputStreamWriter outputWriter=new OutputStreamWriter(fileout);
outputWriter.write("1");
outputWriter.close();
```

I detect the problem when I afterwards execute the app and try to read the file content, through the following code:

```
File f = new File("flag.txt");
if (f.exists())
   Toast.makeText(this, "The file exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
else
   Toast.makeText(this, "The file wasn't created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

But it always follows the "else" branch. Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you use `SharedPreferences` instead? It's simpler. IMO It's really bad idea to make file just for a flag..

Comment: Try new File(getFilesDir(), "flag.txt");

Comment: The problem is that the parent  directory when you call File without explicitly setting it isn't correct.  Use the 2 parameter function and pass it the proper parent.  In face, I'd skip using openFileOutput and instead get an explicit directory like internalFilesDir, just to avoid having to guess where Android is writing that file.

Comment: At the end I decided to use SharedPreferences, which I didn't know before. Thank you everybody

Answer (score 0):

For getting file specify the directory of your file.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "flag.txt");
```